# CreateRenderNode in maya and update the custom UI

Tags: python, maya

I am new to Python, so this might seem trivial. I've search all over the place to find an answer to my problem, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a script, that is like a mini Hypeshade window and its main function is to create materials and load all the texture files that the user chose in one click. I want to have an option though for when the user wants to connect a noise or a checker for example to one of the file inputs (like bump, normal, etc.). This is done in maya by calling the "createRenderNode" window.

Now, I have it workning and it connects to the input that I want to, but I also want to get the name of this file in the corresponding textField in my UI which it doesn't, since, when my function runs, it gets an empty string, as nothing is connected to it yet.

Here is the code I have (I have tried so many iterations):

```
# Error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 49, in brwa
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable #


import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

def UI():

    if cmds.window("MatWindow", exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI("MatWindow")

    mainwindow = cmds.window("MatWindow", t="Dummy UI", bgc=(0.2,0.2,0.2), mnb = False, mxb = False) 
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.rowColumnLayout(nr = 1)
    cmds.textFieldGrp('mtNameTxt', l = "Material Name")
    cmds.setParent ( '..' )
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.button("createlamb", l = "Create Lambert", c = 'lamb()')
    cmds.setParent ( '..' )
    cmds.rowColumnLayout('albclm', nr = 1)   
    cmds.textFieldGrp('albtxt', l = "Albedo", pht = "Albedo Map")
    cmds.iconTextButton('conna', w = 25, h = 20, i = "navButtonUnconnected.png", c = 'brwa()')
    cmds.setParent( '..' )
    cmds.separator(h = 20)
    cmds.text("Insert a name first, then create the lambert, then try to load a texture")
    cmds.showWindow()
    cmds.window("MatWindow", e = 1, w=550, h=150, sizeable = 0)

UI()

#=========== Lambert ===========#    
def lamb():
    matName = cmds.textFieldGrp('mtNameTxt', q = True, text = True)
    if cmds.objExists(matName) :
        cmds.confirmDialog( t = "Error", m = "Material name already exists, please choose another name.", b = "OK") 
    else :
        lambert = cmds.shadingNode("lambert", asShader = True, n = matName)
        shading_group = cmds.sets(r = True, nss = True, em = True, n = '%s_SG' %matName)
        cmds.connectAttr('%s.outColor' %matName ,'%s.surfaceShader' %shading_group)


def brwa():

    matName = cmds.textFieldGrp('mtNameTxt', q = True, text = True)## this gets the material name from the UI
    brwsa = '%s.color' %matName
    pm.defaultNavigation(destination = brwsa, createNew = 1)
    pm.defaultNavigation(destination = brwsa, defaultTraversal = 1) ## this opens the createRenderNode window
    brwsafile = cmds.listConnections(brwsa) ## this gets the connected file

    for fileName in brwsafile:   

        def button_cmd(_):
            # _ is a dummy argument the button sends, but you can ignore it
            cmds.select(fileName)

        cmds.iconTextButton('conna', edit = 1, i = "navButtonConnected.png", c = button_cmd)
        cmds.textFieldGrp('albtxt', edit = 1, text = fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

As written the obvious problem is

```
cmds.iconTextButton('conna', edit = 1, i = "navButtonConnected.png", c = "cmds.select(fileName)")
```

Since you've specified the command as a string, 'fileName' is not being passed to the select command -- this might work intermittently if you have accidentally left a variable named `fileName` in your global scope; but it won't get the loop variable.

You basically never want to pass commands as strings, for reasons spelled out [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet).  Instead, pass a function object directly.  If you define the function inline, this you can even grab relevant variables where the function is defined to simplify passing information around (the link above goes into more detail).

So, something like this:

```
def brwa():

     matName = cmds.textFieldGrp('mtNameTxt', q = True, text = True)## this gets the material name from the UI
     brwsa = matName + ".diffuse_color"                     
     pm.defaultNavigation(destination=brwsa, defaultTraversal=1) ## this opens the createRenderNode window
     brwsafile = cmds.listConnections(brwsa) ## this gets the connected file

     for fileName in brwsafile:   

        def button_cmd(_):
            # _ is a dummy argument the button sends, but you can ignore it
            cmds.select(fileName)

        cmds.iconTextButton('conna', edit = 1, i = "navButtonConnected.png", c = button_cmd)
        cmds.textFieldGrp('albtxt', edit = 1, text = fileName)
```

Your snippet is incomplete, so I can't test it -- but this is the basic issue in the lines you supplied.

Comment: Looking at the longer code, you've got to be able to (1) create the new material and (2) use it in the albedo map button.  This is a good case for a class, rather than a single function, since you can't know all of the info you want until the code is actually running

Comment: I presume your are saying (1) create the file texture* instead of material. So I should create a single class inside my main code that does this? Again sorry for asking that kind of stuff, I am new to all of this. And how I would call it when pushing the button from the main code?

Comment: Also, I managed to make it work by using the `scriptJob` command, and splitting the `brwa()` function in two. One bit is creating the window and the texture file, and only when I actually click to select the file I want from the window the second function runs giving me the names and stuff. But i dont think thats the best way to go about it, it's giving me weird results everytime.